# Why does second HttpClient login to a site fail?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I am developing a web site using .Net MVC. One of the features is a dialogue that scrapes data from another site and records it in a database for subsequent reporting.

The dialogue is controlled by an MVC controller which logs into the other site, retrieves data and  processes it.  If it transpires that there is further data required, the user is alerted and given the option of returning to the site to extract the missing data.  This second step does not have to be done immediately, the dialogue can be returned to at that point and the missing data retrieved.

The code used in the first and second steps to log into the other web site seem identical but whilst the first log in always works and retrieves the data, the second always fails to retrieve any data - a "login required" page is returned.  This occurs whether the two steps are carried out with or without a break.

Logging in manually with the same credentials permits access to all the required data.

I have checked that the correct credentials are being passed each time and checked the `HttpResponseMessage` from the two logins - both return 200 OK.  I have tried storing the `HttpClient` as a class level variable and also as distinct variables in each of the actions.

You will see from the code that have used service classes (to prevent the controller becoming unmanageable).  So I tried putting the second login logic in a separate service so that there was only one `HttpClient` create in each.  Same result.

I'm retired, recreational programmer and both C# and .Net are self-taught so please forgive any naivety in the code that follows which hopefully is sufficient to illustrate the problem.

Update - I tried injecting `HttpClientFactory` into the controller, having that create and save HttpClient as a class vriable which is passed to each of the `ExampleScraper` instantiations.  Same result.

I'm beginning to think I am barking up the wrong tree but I don't know what else could be wrong.

```
using CPGolf.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using XXX.Web.Services;

namespace XXX.Web.Controllers
{

    public class DialogueController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public DialogueController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult GetBasicData()
        {
            var credentials = GetSiteCredentials();
            var siteScraper = new ExampleScraper(credentials);
            var pageHtml = siteScraper.GetSitePage();

            // Etc.

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult GetFurtherData()
        {
            var credentials = GetSiteCredentials();
            var  siteScraper = new ExampleScraper(credentials);
            var furtherPageHtml = siteScraper.GetFurtherSitePage();

            // Etc. 

            return View();
        }
        
        private SiteCredentials GetSiteCredentials()
        {
            SiteCredentials credentials = new SiteCredentials
            {
                Login = _configuration.GetSection("Credentials").GetValue<string>("Login"),
                Pin = _configuration.GetSection("Credentials").GetValue<string>("Pin")
            };
            return credentials;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using XXX.Models.Credentials;
using System.Net;

namespace XXX.Web.Services
{
    public class ExampleScraper
    {
        private string _Login;
        private string _Pin;
        private HttpClient? _client;

        public ExampleScraper(SiteCredentials credentials)
        {
            _Login = credentials.Login;
            _Pin = credentials.Pin;
        }

        public HttpClient GetHttpClient()
        {
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            return new HttpClient(handler);
        }

        public void LogInToSite(HttpClient client)
        {
            string loginUrl = "https://www.example.com/login.php";

            var credentials = new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("memberid", _Login),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("pin", _Pin)
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(credentials);
            HttpResponseMessage loginResult = PostUrl(loginUrl, client, content);
        }

        public void LogOutFromSite()
        {
            _ = CallUrl($"https://www.example.com/?action=logout", _client).Result;
        }

        private static async Task<string> CallUrl(string fullUrl, HttpClient client)
        {
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync(fullUrl);
            return response;
        }

        private HttpResponseMessage PostUrl(string fullUrl, HttpClient client, 
            FormUrlEncodedContent content)
        {
            var response = client.PostAsync(fullUrl, content).Result;
            return response;
        }

        public string GetSitePage()
        {
            _client = GetHttpClient();
            LogInToSite(_client);

            string pageUrl = $"https://www.example.com/......";
            string pageHtml = CallUrl(pageUrl, _client).Result;

            LogOutFromSite();

            return pageHtml;
        }

        public string GetFurtherSitePage()
        {
            _client = GetHttpClient();
            LogInToSite(_client);

            string furtherPageUrl = "http://www.example.com/......";
            string furtherPageHtml = CallUrl(furtherPageUrl, _client).Result;

            LogOutFromSite();

            return furtherPageHtml;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has some bad styles. Your `HttpClient` should or at least could be scoped. Furthermore you never dispose your `HttpClients` and `HttpResponseMessages`. This can lead so some awkward behaviours.

Comment: I recommend to implement the `IDisposable` interface to `ExampleScraper`. Then you are able to set the `HttpClient` in ExampleScrapers constructor and dispose it in your dispose method of `ExampleScraper`.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian.  I thought GC cleaned up everything but I now know that doesn't apply to unmanaged resources.  I've implemented IDisposable as you suggested, it hasn't solved my problem though but it is another lesson learned.  Could you possibly point me to something that explains what you mean by HttpClient being scoped please?

Comment: My comment was a bit inaccurate. What I meaned is that you can declare your `HttpClient` as a private property (as you have) and then dispose it in your dispose method. So the scope of your `HttpClient` is the lifetime scope of your class which implements the client (in your case `ExampleScraper`).

Comment: If you have implemented the IDisposable pattern you need to dispose your object of `ExampleScraper`: `using var siteScraper = new ExampleScraper(credentials);`
Have you done that? Without the `using` or `siteScraper.Dispose()` your dispose method does not getting called.

Comment: I found a simple explanation on the web. The IHttpClientFactory is injected into the controller and stored as a private property,  Prior to instantiating the ExampleScraper, I do var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient and then do new ExampleScraper(credentials, httpClient) and in the constructor I save the httpClient as a private property.  Finally, I added a Dispose method that nulls the private property.  After the controller calls to methods in exampleScraper I do siteScraper.Dispose() Hope that was correct.  It certainly didn't break anything.  Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

This is embarassing. As is now glaringly obvious, the first calls used https but the second used http.

I've learned a lot though thanks to Sebastian.